# get status of SIP invite of Freeswitch

Tags: sip, freeswitch

I am new to Freeswitch.
I have successfully connected two FSs. First FS redirects to second FS.
Now I would like to get the information about the SIP invite; whether it is received at 2nd FS or not programmatically, when call is made to 1st FS. I am open to scripting option as well apart from configuring the xml files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write script which will listen for channel states on ESL interface of second Freeswitch, when call will hit extension of it you should get CHANNEL_CREATE event:

https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Event_List#Channel_events

More about ESL:

https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_event_socket

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am looking for python solution. Can you please elaborate this time?
I am following this link https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Mod_python#Sample_Python_Scripts.

I have added this in dialplan/default.xml
 <condition field="state" expression="CS_NEW">
      <action application="python" data="my_python"/>
    </condition>
The state would be CS_NEW when CHANNEL_CREATE event occurs.
Is this correct approach?

Comment: Now I'm not sure that I understand you. Maybe you can let me know what exactly you need to do after you get confirmation that 2nd FS got the call? What exactly you need to do with your script?

Comment: Actually there is a C/C++ application running alongside 2nd FS. So I need to intimate the C/C++ application about the receipt of sip invite to the 2nd FS. I know Telnetting would be one option as you mentioned earlier. But I am keen on Python approach.

Comment: Ok, then best approach is to do it with ESL. You can write ESL script in python too. Just that script will need to connect to ESL and listen for events. Example which you showed is different script and it is run by Freeswitch when call hit it. Usually this scripts is just extension of Dialplan(or call logic), but you do not need any call logic to be extended, you need to know when call hits freeswitch. Probably you can implement this inside that python script too, but how you will send info to your C/C++ application as this 2 apps will be completely separate?

Comment: In my proposed solution you can call ESL script from C/C++ app(or even you can do this everything inside C/C++ app what from my point of view is the best approach) and get all necessary info back quite easy through standard out.

Comment: I got the right response on freeswitch console when I used the command: /event plain text CHANNEL_CREATE.

But I couldn't get the program snippet I was looking for. The code which I found was either to answer the call or put into conference. If you could help me with the code that would be great

Comment: I used following code.
But the two printfs are printing null after SIP invite is received.
int main(void)
{
 esl_handle_t handle = {{0}};
 esl_event_t **save_event, **p;
  esl_connect(&handle, "localhost", 8021, NULL, "ClueCon");
 printf("Connected\n");
 
  esl_events(&handle, ESL_EVENT_TYPE_PLAIN,"CHANNEL_CREATE");

 if((esl_recv_event(&handle, 1, NULL)) == ESL_SUCCESS)
 {
 printf("bbb = %s\n", (handle.last_ievent->body));
 printf("zzzzz = %s\n", handle.last_sr_event->body);
 }
  
  esl_disconnect(&handle);
  
  return 0;

}

Comment: I think I might have cracked this one.
    
    {
            esl_handle_t handle = {{0}};
            esl_event_t  **p;
            esl_connect(&handle, "localhost", 8021, NULL, "ClueCon");
             esl_events(&handle, ESL_EVENT_TYPE_PLAIN,"CHANNEL_CREATE");

            esl_recv_event(&handle, 1, p);
            if(p==NULL)
            {
                printf("%s\n", handle.last_ievent->event_user_data);
                printf("%s\n", handle.last_event->body);
                printf("%s\n", handle.last_ievent->body);
            }
        esl_disconnect(&handle);
    }